# jQuery mobile causing 404 when in optimization mode or debug is true

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, optimization, http-status-code-404

In my mobile site I receive an error when I go OUT of debug mode and into optimization mode when the page contains svg files.

What is the work around for optimization when there are svg images in the css files so that the image shows up and not a 404?

**I'm using jqm locally.**

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/mobilecss").Include("~/Content/jquery.mobile*", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

-

```
http://localhost:21455/Content/data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%3C!DOCTYPE%20svg%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD%20SVG%201.1%2F%2FEN%22%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%3Csvg%20version%3D%221.1%22%20id%3D%22Layer_1%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22%20x%3D%220px%22%20y%3D%220px%22%20%20width%3D%228px%22%20height%3D%2212px%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%208%2012%22%20style%3D%22enable-background%3Anew%200%200%208%2012%3B%22%20xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cpolygon%20fill%3D%22%23FFF%22%20points%3D%222%2C0%200%2C2%204%2C6%200%2C10%202%2C12%208%2C6%20%22%2F%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E
```

---

```
GET http://localhost:21455/Content/data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3C%3Fxm…E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3Cg%3E%3C%2Fg%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E 400 (Bad Request) jquery-2.0.3.js:6349
vt jquery-2.0.3.js:6349
x.extend.css jquery-2.0.3.js:6326
x.cssHooks.(anonymous function).set jquery-2.0.3.js:6535
x.extend.style jquery-2.0.3.js:6293
(anonymous function) jquery-2.0.3.js:8788
x.extend.access jquery-2.0.3.js:779
x.fn.(anonymous function) jquery-2.0.3.js:8760
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:8150
a.extend.hideIn jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:8128
a.extend.startIn jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:8146
a.extend.doneOut jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:8127
a.extend.transition jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:8214
a.widget._cssTransition jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:7512
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:4147
a.widget.transition jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:7754
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:4147
a.widget.change jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:7587
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:4147
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:4218
x.extend.each jquery-2.0.3.js:590
x.fn.x.each jquery-2.0.3.js:237
a.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:4210
a.mobile.changePage jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:7845
a.mobile.gradeA.a.extend.initializePage jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:14733
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js:14733
l jquery-2.0.3.js:2913
c.fireWith jquery-2.0.3.js:3025
x.extend.ready jquery-2.0.3.js:398
```

---

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
```

```
Bad Request - Invalid URL

HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.
```

Comment: are you using jQ & jQM CDN-hosted or locally? are you getting _failed to load resource ---- jquery.map_?

Comment: I've updated my question for your request.